# Search by first three letters from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

**movie_table**

```
id  movie_name      genre   rating
1   Green lantern   action  7.5
2   Seven           horror  8.5
4   django          comedy  6.0
```

**tv_serial**

```
id  serial_name     genre   rating
1   game of throne  action  9.5
2   walking dead    horror  8.5
4   breaking bad    comedy  6.0
```

Now if I put any name starting with G in the search bar the list must show green lantern and game of throne. Just need the sql query to extract these data thank you.

**Edit**

To sound more generalized and to be helpful for others, this question is rephrased as:
How to implement [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) in php where data is obtained from a mysql table?

Comment: Any effort? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920657/mysql-autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query :

```
SELECT movie_name as Name
FROM movie_table
WHERE movie_name like 'G%'
union all
SELECT serial_name as Name
FROM tv_serial
WHERE serial_name like 'G%'
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55618/4)

Comment: @user2567647 , is it helpful to you ?